# Where can I get a free rich text editor

Tags: asp.net

I would like a free rich text editor that maintains color formatiing of asp.net applications.
The editors that I have checked are not maintaining the exact copied data. There are linse breaks in between.

Comment: Very opinionated, sorry, voting to close. There are NUMEROUS of controls like this, some of which are free, others paid... An example of free editor might be `HtmlEditor` in `AjaxControlToolkit` found here http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx

Comment: You want an online Text Editor to add to your Asp.net application? Or a Text Editor to code Asp.net code?

Comment: I have just managed to create a rich text editor but the problem is that I am getting line breaks when I copy paste the source code from c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular is probably [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). But you didn't say which editors you have already tried.

Comment: Yes, see http://ckeditor.com/about/license. There is also premium version if you can't use GPL, LGPL or MPL license. http://cksource.com/ckeditor

Comment: ckeditor is not maintaining c# code color on copy paste

Comment: I'd suggest using http://codemirror.net/ rather than storing formatting info.

Comment: See e.g. http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html

Comment: Is there a way to maintain colors with CKEditor? For eg:- C# code color and Html markup color? Can it be maintained?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28194/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-rocky)

Answer (score 2):

Tinymce is also good option : http://www.tinymce.com/index.php I have used earlier and it works fine

Comment: I have found tinymce 4.0 to be more compatible when used with AjaxControlToolkit controls than CKEditor